# Openshift Monitoring with REST_API

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rbac, openshift-enterprise, azure-rbac

I am trying to use Openshift REST-API's to get the status of my cron-jobs. I am the admin of my namespace but I don't have cluster access so I can't do anything on cluster level.

Now, to get the status, I am first creating the role :

```
# oc create role podreader --verb=get --verb=list --verb=watch --resource=pods,cronjobs.batch,jobs.batch
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/podreader created
```

But when I try to add a role to a service account it fails.

```
# oc create serviceaccount nagios 
# oc policy add-role-to-user podreader system:serviceaccount:uc-immoscout-dev:nagios
Warning: role 'podreader' not found
Error from server (NotFound): clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "podreader" not found
```

My main intention is to to get the status of my cron-jobs, jobs and pods which I am scheduling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add `--role-namespace=namespace-of-role` to the `oc policy add-role-to-user` command otherwise the role is treated as a cluster role.

From the docs:

> --role-namespace='': namespace where the role is located: empty means a role defined in cluster policy

Comment: Thanks for alot koe. The role is added properly still I am not able to get the status of my cronjob. 

"status": "Failure",
"message": "cronjobs.batch \"mycronjob\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:myproject-namespace:nagios\" cannot get cronjobs.batch/status in the namespace \"myproject-namespace\": no RBAC policy matched",

 "group": "batch",
 "kind": "cronjobs"
"code": 403

Commands Used : 

# oc serviceaccounts get-token nagios
# curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' https://$ENDPOINT/apis/batch/v2alpha1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/cronjobs

Comment: I guess you should create another question for this.